# how to solve empty index.html issue with wget?

Tags: command-line, download, wget

I want to download all files in a folder on remote server I use Wget on windows client my command is :

```
>wget -r http://www.example.com/getfeed/d165161dasdvc561551as1v6/soccerfixtures/england/
```

this line give me index.html size(0 KB).

i used then :

```
>wget -r --reject "index.html*" http://www.example.com/getfeed/d165161dasdvc561551as1v6/soccerfixtures/england/
```

Now I do not get any files even when I exclude the index.html I still do not get any file downloaded could anybody help me with this and tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

This would only work if the web server on the opposite end is configured to give you a directory listing. Not all servers are configured this way. Most automatically redirect you to an index.html, index.php, etc, which you've asked wget to ignore.

In the first case, where you do not ignore index.html, wget will only follow links in that page. Since the size of the index.html returned by the web server is zero, then there are no links for wget to follow, and it terminates. Wget has no way of explicitly knowing what files are in the directory.

Edit to address comment:

$ wget -i download-file-list.txt

Comment: first of all I have a list of files in each directory and I try to download a file and it works with Wget but my problem now that I have more than 300 XML files in differenet directories and I want to download them using Wget, Is there anyway to make a script to do that? I need to know what is the best way, best language and could the remote server prevents the process if it takes too long?

Comment: See the edit I added to my answer. That sounds kinda like what you're asking.